# JSON response customize the response content

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have implemented a spring mvc 3 code to obtain JSON response (with help of jackson mapper)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getallroles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JsonJtableResponse1 getAllRoles(){
    List<Role> roleList = testService.getAllRoles();
    JsonJtableResponse1 jstr = new JsonJtableResponse1("OK",roleList);
    return jstr;
}
```

The JSON response object is like this.

```
public class JsonJtableResponse1 {

    private String Result;

    private List<Role> Records;

    public JsonJtableResponse1(String Result) {
        this.Result = Result;
    }

    public JsonJtableResponse1(List<Role> Records) {
        this.Records = Records;
    }

    public JsonJtableResponse1(String Result, List<Role> Records) {
        this.Result = Result;
        this.Records = Records;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return Result;
    }

    public void setResult(String Result) {
        this.Result = Result;
    }

    public List<Role> getRecords() {
        return Records;
    }

    public void setRecords(List<Role> Records) {
        this.Records = Records;
    }   
}
```

returned JSON from spring method getAllRoles() is

```
{"result":"OK","records":[
{"custId":"1","name":"aaa","birthYear":"1982","employer":"XX","infoAsOfDate":"20130110","disabled":"true"},
{"custId":"2","name":"bbb","birthYear":"1982","employer":"YY","infoAsOfDate":"20130111","disabled":"true"},
{"custId":"3","name":"ccc","birthYear":"1982","employer":"XX","infoAsOfDate":"20130108","disabled":"false"},
{"custId":"4","name":"ddd","birthYear":"1981","employer":"TT","infoAsOfDate":"20130107","disabled":"true"}
]}
```

I need JSON as - [NOTE UPPER CASE R in both elements]

```
{"Result":"OK","Records":[ ....................
 ..............................................
]}
```

with Jakson mapper the JSON response is created taking in to account the getter/setter names of the object .How can I achieve the required format of JSON response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customized names using the annotation `@JsonProperty`:

```
@JsonProperty("Result")
public String getResult() {
    return Result;
}
```

If you need to have all your properties names to have the first letter to be in upper case, you could change the default naming convention by extending the `PropertyNamingStrategy`. For example you can read this blog post http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/03/entry_448.html.